# In Euclidean geometry, is there a topic of "the shortest construction"?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

How do we judge if a certain ruler-and-compass construction is the shortest? For example "the shortest construction of a regular pentagon."

Is there a software that can come up with a construction of a geometrical item given a collection of input data?